# How to iterate nested if statements?

Tags: r

I am writing a function in R to disambiguate a vector of city names. The basic idea, is to write a function that returns the original values whenever they match with a lookup table, otherwise attempts to clean the data in various ways (for example fuzzy matching, deleting punctuations, etc...).

I have tried to summarize the logic in this example:

```
x <- "sun fish"
s <- function(x) {
  if (x=='animal') {                #condition A
    return(paste(x,"is an animal"))
  } else if (x=='fish') {           #condition B
    return(paste(x,"is a fish"))
  } else {                          #condition C (does some cleaning)
    x <- sapply(strsplit(x," "),'[[',2)
    return(paste(x, "is something else"))
  }
}
s(x)
```

What would be the best approach to pass again `x` through condition A and condition B if condition C is entered?

Comment: Use `switch()` instead of `if()`

Comment: This is called *recursion*. Just call your function again `else{x <- sapply(...); return(s(x))}`. But make sure to have a limiting case - you'll need to have `s` recognize and stop if it can't split and re-call itself any more or you'll enter an infinite loop.

Comment: @Gregor thanks, shall I put a new if statement that targets the error message or would you look if the object I am assigning the `sapply()` to exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursion to apply your test again:

```
x <- "sun fish"
s <- function(x) {
        if (x=='animal') {                #condition A
                return(paste(x,"is an animal"))
        } else if (x=='fish') {           #condition B
                return(paste(x,"is a fish"))
        } else {                          #condition C (does some cleaning)
                y <- sapply(strsplit(x," "),'[[',2)
                if(x!=y) return(s(y))
                return(paste(x, "is something else"))
        }
}
s(x)
[1] "fish is a fish"
```

#### Edit:

The code above doesn't work for **something elses**. This should fix it while keeping the full name of the animal:

```
x <- c("animal", "sun fish", "an other bug")
s <- function(x) {
        ifelse(x=='animal', 
               paste(x,"is an animal"),
               ifelse(x=='fish',
                      paste(x,"is a fish"), 
                      ifelse(lengths(strsplit(x, " "))>1, 
                             paste(sub("([a-z]*) .*", "\\1", x), 
                                   s(sub("[a-z]* (.+)", "\\1", x))),
                             paste(x, "is something else"))))
}
s(x)
[1] "animal is an animal"            "sun fish is a fish"             "an other bug is something else"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `switch()` instead of multiple `if()` calls:

```
x <- "sun fish"
s <- function(x) {
  z <- switch(x, 
              animal = "is an animal",
              fish = "is a fish",
              "is something else"
  )
  paste(x, z)
}
```

The result:

```
s(x)
[1] "sun fish is something else"
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess my example was a bit confusing. I would like the output to be `"sun fish is a fish"`

Comment: Well then, just modify the last bit of the function to do what you need it to do. You now have the model for using `switch()` to make your code simpler.

Comment: Have you considered the "cleaning" part? Would you still consider `switch` a preferable approach?